# How to set size of VerticalFieldManager on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, layout, java-me

There is a ListField in VerticalFieldManager and I want to fix the height of VerticalFieldManager. Because there is an endless blank area at the bottom of ListField.

Comment: Better say what you're trying to achieve. It looks like you are doing some hack, when it is possible to get the same in a simple and right way.

Comment: The problem is that when i put a listfield into VerticalFieldManager there is always a blank space below listfield. I don't want to see any white space after the last element of listfield. Is it clear now? What is the simple and right way now?

Comment: So do you know the answer or you just wrote comment for nothing?

Comment: Please see my answer. I still feel like a fixed heigt VFM is not what you need. However this is up to you. Peace.

Comment: Are you using the USE_ALL_HEIGHT style bit when creating your VFM? If so remove it and just add the list as normal and it should only be the height of the list.

Comment: @user696371  Politeness goes a long way.  When you say "So do you know the answer or you just wrote comment for nothing?" it comes across as impatient and extremely rude.  You waited an entire hour to hit your impatience limit, which is way, way too short for a volunteer driven site.

Comment: You are right, i am aware of my rudeness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one:

```
public class FixedHeightVerticalFieldManager extends VerticalFieldManager {

    private int height;

    public FixedHeightVerticalFieldManager(int height) {
         super(VERTICAL_SCROLL | VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);
         this.height = height;
    }

    protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
        super.sublayout(maxWidth, height);
        setExtent(maxWidth, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: @tipycalFlow: Could you tell what you mean under "manager properties"? Sorry if this is a silly question. :)

Comment: u can add this constructor `public FixedHeightVerticalFieldManager(int height,int managerProperties) {
         super(managerProperties);
         this.height = height;
    }`

Comment: @tipycalFlow: Sure, you're right. It was not done in a way you propose just because the code was provided with the only goal - to demonstrate a way of how to get a VFM with a fixed height. But in a real project it surely should have been improved.

Comment: Hmmm ... you're right. I proposed it only to improve it- didn't see the bigger picture.